# production ready persistence providers for jpa 2.1

Tags: java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

Is there a Production ready Persistence provider for JPA 2.1? I see that Hibernate is only going to support it only from 4.3 onwards and its only in a beta stage.

Comment: not yet, EclipseLink also on the way. see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using eclipselink 2.5.1. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/. Seems to work stable.

Comment: Are you using it on a live production environment?